# Corrupt disk after fsck for ntfs

Tags: linux, partitioning, ntfs, fsck

A while ago, I found out that I could not use my 2TB type 07 (NTFS) USB disk when connected to a computer with a Windows boot.

Disk had only one partition.

However, I could mount and use it under Ubuntu. So, I went on to do a fsck for NTFS under Ubuntu. It said that there were errors on the disk and that the MBR was written. It advised me to run CHKDSK /F under Windows. This operation made the disk unusable under Ubuntu, too.

When I went on to go and run Gnome Disk Utility to find out what's going on with the disk, I've seen that it listed 5 volumes, Free - Unknown - Unknown - Free - Free, respectively.

I'd like to note that Windows reports these "Unknown" partitions as "healthy."

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Thanks, ernie. I just wanted to know about the means to save the volume. It looks like "Active File Recovery" application is doing just fine. I'll also try TestDisk.

Answer (score 0):

Running additional tools on the partitions runs the risk of damaging the filesystem(s) further and destroying your data permanently. If your data is worth paying professional recovery prices for, I advise you not use the drive further and send it in.

If you are more of a DIYer, the proper way to run recovery tools, chkdsk, etc on a corrupted filesystem is to do it on an image instead of the original disk. That way you can try something and if it doesn't work, revert to the original image. You can make a disk image with the dd and ddrescue tools in the Ubuntu terminal like this:
ddrescue /dev/yourdrive imagename.image imagename.log
dd if=/dev/yourdrive of=imagename.image

Ddrescue makes it much easier to rescue data from drives with bad sectors when compared with dd.
Then just make a copy of those images to be sure you are working on a backup

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ddrescue to build an image of your usb.
Later, use testdisk on this image in order to try to recover your data.
With your data recovered, you can destroy all partitions and format your usb with windows tools. Please use windows tools for checking windows filesystems if you can. Specialy for NTFS filesystems.

Both tools are avalaible for most linux distributions, testdisk is avalaible in windows and linux.

Ddrescue:
https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/

Testdisk:
https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk